# basic Ruby TCP server demo fails on startup: `bind': Address already in use, Errno::EADDRINUSE

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp

I am presenting a simple TCP server demo in Ruby. My first demo is using classical C-style bind-listen-accept-read-write-close methods. This code works well for the first time:

```rb
require 'socket'

class Server

  def start(bind: '127.0.0.1', port: nil, backlog: 1)

    Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM).tap do |sock|
      sock.bind Addrinfo.tcp bind, port
      sock.listen backlog

      # the codes of client connecting with it here is for reproducing the issue more easily
      c = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM)
      c.connect Addrinfo.tcp '127.0.0.1', port

      client, client_addr = sock.accept
      puts "connected from #{client_addr.ip_address}:#{client_addr.ip_port}"

      client.puts "hi"

      client.close
      sock.close

    end
  end

end

Server.new.start(port: 23333)
```

However when I tried to run it again, I got an errors of `EADDRINUSE`:

```
`some-script.rb:8:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:23333 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)`
```

After about 30 seconds, I can start the script successfully again. Not sure if this is done by the kernel.

Dosn't `Socket#close` fully close the socket and kernel close the TCP connection?

I tried it on both Mac OS 10.11.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 and got the same result.
After reading ruby's source code (socket.c) I still can't figure it out.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this by calling `sock.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_REUSEADDR, true)` before the call to `sock.bind()`.